# Lua script for scan with 'match' and 'count' constraints

Tags: lua, redis, parameter-passing, jedis

I am using **Jedis**. I need a **Lua** script to scan for a pattern with a specified limit. I don't know how to pass the parameters inside Lua script.
Sample Code:

```
String script="return     {redis.call('SCAN',KEYS[1],'COUNT',KEYS[2],'MATCH',KEYS[3]}";
List<String> response = (List<String>)jedis.eval(script,cursor,COUNT,pattern);
```

How do I pass these parameters to the script?

Comment: Why not just call Jedis' `.scan` instead? Anyway, your script should not use the `KEYS` array but the `ARGV` array instead - read about Lua scripting in Redis at http://redis.io/commands/eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several points to fix.

- In scan command, 'match' parameter should be placed prior to 'count'.
- You should only use KEYS when it is a place for Redis key. Other things should be represented to ARGV.
- You forgot to specify key count while calling Jedis.eval().

So, fixed version of your code is,

`String script="return {redis.call('SCAN',ARGV[1],'MATCH',ARGV[2],'COUNT',ARGV[3])}";
List<String> response = (List<String>)jedis.eval(script, 0, cursor, pattern, COUNT);`

But I agree Itamar to use Jedis.scan() instead.

Hope this helps.